# MySQL Subtract Date Time and insert results into a new Column

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a MySQL database, I use Heidi SQL to access it.  The following columns are part of one of my tables:

| START_DATE | START_TIME | STOP_DATE | STOP_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-10-2022 | 02:30:00 | 01-10-2022 | 03:30:00 |

What I need is to subtract start date/time from stop date/time and then create or insert into a 5th column called duration (in minutes), in this case the 5th column would get populated with 60.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, Shawn, _I use Headi SQL to access it_ Do you mean HeidiSQL? https://www.heidisql.com/

Answer (score 1):

See [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Since the DURATION column is to be the 5th column, I am assuming that each of the columns above are separated.

Using MySQL, you could try:

```
    SELECT *,
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,START_TIME, STOP_TIME) AS DURATION
    FROM
     TABLENAME;
```

The resulting query will display all your previous columns and add on the DURATION column as well. You may save the query to a table when you are done.

All of this is assuming that your working columns, as above, are in DATETIME. To check the information about a table's structure: [DESCRIBE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/describe.html)